# Change default Text Color Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

Where can I change the default Text Color in the Material UI Theme?

Setting `primary`, `secondary` and `error` works

```
const styles = { a: 'red', b: 'green', ... };

createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
          light: styles.a,
          main: styles.b,
          dark: styles.c,
          contrastText: styles.d
        },
        secondary: {
          light: styles.aa,
          main: styles.bb,
          dark: styles.cc,
          contrastText: styles.dd
        },
        error: {
          light: styles.aaa,
          main: styles.bbb,
          dark: styles.ccc,
          contrastText: styles.ddd,
        },
    ...,
    }
...,
}
```

Now, when I use a `<Typography />` component, I can do this

```
<Typography
  color='primary'
  variant='h6'>
  Foo
</Typography>
```

That gives it the color I defined in `palette.primary.main`.

However, when I leave the `color` prop empty

```
<Typography
  variant='h6'>
  Foo
</Typography>
```

I gives the a greyish color. Where is that color defined? Where can I define additional text colors despited `primary`, `secondary` and `error`?

Simplay adding another key to `palette` is not working...

```
createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        ...,
        text1: {
          light: styles.t,
          main: styles.tt,
          dark: styles.ttt,
          contrastText: styles.tttt,
        },
    ...
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is done like this.

```
createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        ...,
        text: {
          primary: styles.t,
          secondary: styles.tt,
          disabled: styles.ttt,
          hint: styles.tttt,
        },
    ...
    }
...
}
```

Make sure that `primary` is a `color code`, not an `object`.
The colors can be used like so

```
<Typography
    color='textPrimary'> // or 'textSecondary', 'hint', 'disabled'
    Foo Bar
</Typography>
```

Comment: Too bad the documentation doesn't mention the color part!! O_O

Answer (score 9):

If you want to change the default color of the "material-ui" Typography components, you can use this kind of code.

```
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';

const MuiTheme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    allVariants: {
      color: 'red'
    }
  }
});

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={MuiTheme}>
      <Typography>Hi there</Typography>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This will change the Typography components' default color to whatever you would like to be (for this example, it makes the default color red), of course it will be changed by using "color" prop in the Typography component.

Comment: Is there a way to change the default color and I don't have to explicitly use the color prop?

Comment: Thanks this worked for me!
I first defined the color on all variants and below custom values for other tags.
Now you just can use Typography component without adding a prop for the color, just choose the variant and your theming will handle the rest!